# how to sum based on groups in tableau

Tags: sql, distinct, tableau-api

So I have 2 tables joined in Tableau. First table is 3 projects by contract:
Project | Contract | Location | Amount
project1 | contract1 | texas | 100
project1 | contract2 | texas | 200
project1 | contract3 | texas | 300
project2 | contract1 | new york | 1000
project2 | contract2 | new york | 2000
project2 | contract3 | new york | 3000

Second table is contract details:
Project | Contract | Detail | Risk
project1 | contract1 | a | 0.5
project1 | contract1 | b | 0.9
project1 | contract1 | c | 0.99
project2 | contract3 | a | 0.2
project2 | contract3 | b | 0.45
project2 | contract3 | c | 0.33

I am making a dashboard so these tables have to be joined, the problem is once joined the resulting table has duplicates in the first tables amount field. So if i want the sum(amount) by location, it calculates:
100 + 100 + 100 + 200 + 300 for texas, when i want 100+200+300. How do I just get the sum for texas from the first table now that i joined tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically talking.. not knowing the tableu specific issues you may be having..

If the Detail / Risk Information is not relevant to the work that you are doing then select the distinct values BEFORE joining.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
     (Distinct Project,Contract) Table2 AS a
     INNER JOIN Table1 as b
         ON a.Project = b.Project
         AND a.Contract = B.Contract
```

If that other data is relevant to you then you need to figure out how to de-normalise it.. in this case how will you split the risk accross the matching rows to create a single row per region. .. say it was not risk say it was a break down of expenses that you wanted to add up you could do this

```
SELECT 
    b.*
    ,sum(a.cost)
FROM 
     Table2 AS a
     INNER JOIN Table1 as b
         ON a.Project = b.Project
         AND a.Contract = B.Contract
GROUP BY
    a.Project
    a.Contract
```

Not sure if that helps any?

Hmm.. this is going to be tricky without knowing exactly what you are working with.. but i have two suggestions:

1. Create a project-Contract column by adding these two fields together and join on that instead.

for example when using powerpivot in excel and i am working with sales orders i will often have to create columns like :`=A1&"-"&B1` to give me a "1234-10" type result.

2. Normalize (using views in the DB) out your projects into a table on their own (maybe with a summed cost in it) so that all other tables just link on that. -  i would have to play with that to see how it panned out.

..i am just kinda putting those ideas out there as they may help, but sorry if they are just confusing.

Comment: I am thinking that joins are something you are working with in Tableu.. in which case can you create a view in the DB that selects Distinct Project,Contract?

Comment: Thanks gordatron, the detail is important because I'm using a drill down into that with the dashboard. I'm just trying to create a map in tableau with the locations + sum(amount) - when clicked on in the dashboard opens up details.

Comment: Added some extra suggestions there.. sorry if they are no use

Comment: Thanks gordatron for everything, I decided to just simplify the first table into only showing projects, removing contracts and summarizing the info using SQL.